# Irregular #1004 error on Worksheet.[Pictures./Range.]Paste

Tags: excel, vba, winapi

Macro goal: screenshots making of windows desktop application.

Macro fails *irregularly* in last shown line of sub:

```
Sub MakeScreenShot()
    ...
    ClearClipboard
    AltPrintScreen
    wsShots.Activate
    wsShots.Range("B2").Select
    wsShots.Pictures.Paste
    ...
End sub
```

Found that:

- 1004 error happens due to empty clipboard
- in most cases right after error is occurred (when VBE is highlighting the error line) on switching to Excel UI can see that clipboard is *not* empty
- on pasting clipboard then can see screenshot of VBE window with highlighted yellow line
- error happening is highly correlated with PC CPU usage over 40-50% (re-searched by Task Manager)

Assumption:
due to clipboard content (VBE screenshot) on error happening, it looks like in some cases WinAPI calls (keybd_event) stuck (by what reason?) in some queue and OS sends it back to VBE.
Tried to add `Sleep` and/or `DoEvents` right after `AltPrintScreen`, didnt find the difference.

Definition for AltPrintScreen:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub KeybdEvent Lib "user32" Alias "keybd_event" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
Enum KeybdEventEnum
    KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = &H2
    VK_SNAPSHOT = &H2C
    VK_MENU = &H12
End Enum

Sub AltPrintScreen()
    KeybdEvent VK_MENU, 0, 0, 0
    KeybdEvent VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, 0, 0
    KeybdEvent VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0
    KeybdEvent VK_MENU, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0
    Sleep 50
End Sub
```

Please assist; this makes me crazy, it takes several days to localize the issue.

Comment: What is the purpose of selecting the cell B2 before pasting? Is that where you want the picture to be anchored? You generally want to avoid using `.Activate` and `.Select` unless they are for actual user experience functionality since they are inefficient and can lead to problems. I would try just pasting the picture directly and setting the `.Top` and `.Left`  attributes to that of the worksheet cell to get it aligned.

Comment: Selecting the cell B2 as place for pasting.
Will try/do to avoid using .Activate and .Select.

Comment: From [keybd_event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-keybd_event): *"This function has been superseded. **Use [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) instead.**"* To reliably know, when clipboard data is available, you'll have to [Monitoring Clipboard Contents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard#monitoring-clipboard-contents). A `Sleep 50` won't do.

Comment: Try to narrow down the problem. You can comment  ` wsShots.Range("B2").Select`, then paste it directly to see if it is successful.

Comment: 1) Moved out `.Activate` and `("B2").Select` as far as possible from Copy/Paste. My understanding was to exclude all actions between Copy/Paste. It helped to avoid issue, but not at all. 2) Focused on `Sleep 50` in `PrintScreen`, [Monitoring Clipboard Contents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard#monitoring-clipboard-contents) helped. Re-implemented `Sleep 50` with `GetClipboardSequenceNumber`. Minimal testing scenario works for now (without `keybd_event` re-placement)!! Will do and run complete testing scenario soon and put results here.

Comment: For been clear: `("B2").Select` was a part of copy-pasting sequence. So far as overall macro goal is "screenshots making..." and saving it into file, it (macro) did it in two steps. Step1: do PrtScr and paste screenshot into worksheet B2; Step2: copy shape from B2 into Chart object and then export it into file. Since yesterday I re-implemented two copy/paste's into just one of it: do PrtScr and paste into Chart. `("B2").Select` is no longer required.

Comment: So, have your problem solved?

Comment: Hi, thanks to all for comments and help.
Sorry for delay with answer.

@StriveSun-MSFT , yes, the problem has been solved. The key for solving is usage of ```GetClipboardSequenceNumber```, described in [Monitoring Clipboard Contents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard#monitoring-clipboard-contents).

Comment: @IInspectable , please put your comment as answer and I will mark it as solution for my case.
Thank you very much!